# pydantic v2: ClassVar attribute is taken from parent class instead of current class

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic-v2

I have this simple code:

```
import pydantic
from typing import ClassVar
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr


class Parent(pydantic.BaseModel):
    _attribute: str = PrivateAttr('parent_private_attribute')
    
class Child(Parent):
    _attribute: ClassVar[str] = 'child_class_attribute'
```

I would expected that if i do

```
Child._attribute
```

ill get the `'child_class_attribute'` string.

but what happens is:

```
Child._attribute
'parent_private_attribute'
```

While if i access that attribute in the parent class i get:

```
ModelPrivateAttr(default='parent_private_attribute')
```

Why when i try to access Child._attribute i dont get the ClassVar i defined, and instead get the parent private attribute?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Maybe open an issue in the Pydantic GitHub...